# Handling @CreatedBy, @CreatedAt, @ChangedBy, @ChangedAt and @Version fields with spring-data-rest

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I am having trouble making sure data in fields annotated with `@CreatedBy`, `@CreatedAt`, @ChangedBy`,`@ChangedAt`and`@Version`while using`spring-data-rest`. It is behaving in unexpected ways.

1. Calling the `PUT` endpoint while the body doesn't have the fields marked `@CreatedAt` and `@ChangedAt` are setting those fields to `null`. I have worked around this by annotating those fields with `updatable = false`.
2. Calling the `POST`endpoint with random (and incorrect) `@CreatedBy`, `@CreatedAt`, `@ChangedBy`, `@ChangedAt` is ignoring those values and correctly setting the values for those values.
3. Calling the `POST` endpoint with some random value for the `@Version` is setting that incorrect value into the field. I have tried setting `insertable = false` but that didn't work due to the not null constraint.

I am confused at this point how to make sure that these fields are not corrupted by bad request bodies from the rest endpoints. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

As these properties should not be modifiable by the client you should mark them as read only.

```
@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
private String someField;
```

You can either do this directly on the Entity or, to prevent you having to introduce Jackson annotations to your entities, you can can handle via a Jackson Mixin class.

See: https://dzone.com/articles/jackson-mixin-to-the-rescue

You can register a Mixin using the following configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class RepositoryConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder objectMapperBuilder;

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        objectMapperBuilder.mixIn(SomeClass.class, SomeClassMixin.class);

        return objectMapperBuilder.build();
    }

}
```

Comment: I believe this will prevent values being written **only** when the request body is mapped to the entity object cause I would still like Hibernate to handle the Audit annotated fields to be modified.

Comment: Sorry but I have no idea what your comment means. Where else would the request body be mapped to?

Comment: Sorry for that. I will reiterate the question. Will the above configuration prevent Hibernate from updating the fields annotated with `@CreatedBy`, `@CreatedAt`, `@ChangedBy`, `@ChangedAt` and `@Version`?

Comment: These JSON annotations are clearly only applicable at the web binding level i.e. when the request body is deserialised.

Comment: @AlanHay — Or for any other JSON serialization you're doing of the entity (which is one advantage of the mixin suggestion: you can still deserialize them in other JSON contexts).